# What boxes is Watson Bryant referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, richard-jewell

In *Richard Jewell* (2019), Richard Jewell's attorney Watson Bryant tells journalist Kathy Scruggs:

> WATSON BRYANT: We welcome the FBI. We're glad they are here.
>
> KATHY SCRUGGS: No you don't.
>
> WATSON BRYANT: You know that's not true, Kathy. **Can I see those boxes, please?**

What boxes is Watson talking about?

Comment: I think a description or screenshot or link to a video of the context could make things a lot clearer..

Answer (score 1):

He's referring to the boxes of "evidence" that the FBI has taken from Jewell's house.

Bryant is not talking to Scruggs, he's shouting at the FBI agents who are carrying the boxes away from Jewell's house.

Answer (score 1):

Jewel's mother, Bobbi, had just complained that the FBI was removing her underwear from the apartment.  Watson wanted to get a look inside the boxes to see if what they were taking was legal to remove.